# Is 'rocket launcher' the correct name for a weapon?

Tags: word-usage

I have played several games which include the weapon that shoots out projectiles.
Examples are Doom and Half-Life.
But I have a question. Is it correct to call it rocket laucher? To my mind, rocket laucher is something that shoots rockets. And I always thought that a rocket is a spaceship (e. g. a spaceship you must launch in Half-Life, chapter 8 'On a rail').
Wouldn't it be more correctly to call the weapon *missile launcher*, as for example in the Crysis game?

Comment: A rocket certainly is not a space-ship. Space-ships usually _use_ rockets. Just for reference, have a look at the lyrics of the [national anthem of the USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star-Spangled_Banner), which mentions rockets, but was written before there were space-ships :) Also, a _missile_ is basically anything you _send_ away from you - it can be a rock you throw or an ICBM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A gun uses a wad of explosive to launch a bullet or a shell. Once it leaves the barrel of the gun, the bullet or shell loses speed progressively. A [rocket](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rocket) is a device that is powered by burning either solid fuel or a mixture of two liquids: once launched, it keeps gaining speed until wind resistance matches for force generated by the rocket.

Long before spaceships existed, there were rockets: the chinese invented [gunpowder](http://kaleidoscope.cultural-china.com/en/10Kaleidoscope8482.html) in the 9th century, and its usage for weapons came soon after.  Initially, they attached gunpowder-filled tubes to arrows and fired the arrows: pretty soon they realised that the arrow could be self-powered.

The Russians were big fans of rockets as weapons. During world war II, they developed the [Katyusha rocket launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyusha_rocket_launcher), and it is still in use. Meanwhile, America was working on shoulder-fired rockets for anti-tank use, and produced the [M1A1 Rocket launcher](http://www.militaryfactory.com/smallarms/detail.asp?smallarms_id=69) in 1942. They now have portable rocket launcher systems that can guide the rocket to the target, for example this one:

[image]

Comment: Pretty good, except that wire-guided missiles date back to WWII, and shoulder-launched guided missiles to the 1950s - they're neither a recent development nor an American one.  :-)

Comment: @stangdon, Agreed.  A complete summary would have to include Germany's contribution too... from Nebel's Mirak to Wernher von Braun's V2.